# Amazon refund shipping (pre-paid label) XML feed

Tags: xml, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I've been attempting to generate a POST_PAYMENT_ADJUSTMENT_DATA feed to process refunds for customers who have returned items. While the majority of the feed functions as expected, I've encountered an issue: the system consistently overlooks the value I assign to **ReturnShipping**. I believe this value should represent the amount charged to the customer for the prepaid return label they generated. However, it's not being acknowledged or processed accordingly.

**RestockingFee**, **Principal** and **Tax** are working as expected.

I suspect the document version is wrong but unfortunately I haven't find any documentation about this. I tried 1.01 and 1.02.

Do you see what's wrong with my document? Thanks for the help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderAdjustment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderAdjustment>
            <AmazonOrderID>XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX</AmazonOrderID>
            <ActionType>Refund</ActionType>
            <AdjustedItem>
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>XXXXXXXXX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <AdjustmentReason>CustomerReturn</AdjustmentReason>
                <ItemPriceAdjustments>
                    <Component>
                        <Type>ReturnShipping</Type>
                        <Amount currency="USD">-3.900000</Amount>
                    </Component>
                    <Component>
                        <Type>Principal</Type>
                        <Amount currency="USD">20.0000</Amount>
                    </Component>
                    <Component>
                        <Type>Tax</Type>
                        <Amount currency="USD">1.4000</Amount>
                    </Component>
                    <Component>
                        <Type>RestockingFee</Type>
                        <Amount currency="USD">-4.00000</Amount>
                    </Component>
                </ItemPriceAdjustments>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </AdjustedItem>
        </OrderAdjustment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue and this is the Answer from Amazon:

"Hello,

We confirm with the team the reason you are able to do the refund via seller central is seller central in EU allowing a small amount of extra money refund to buyer however, in API we do not have such features, API could only refund the money charging from sellers while they place the order.

Also we confirm with the team we don not have plan to enable this features in SP-API in the recent future.

We are sorry for the inconvenience.

So, in this case, if you would like to refund the return shipment label the only way is do it in seller central, or you could contact seller support to know more about the amazon auto approval refund label, this is also an automatic process to handle the payment for the return label.
https://www.sellercentral.amazon.dev/help/center

https://www.sellercentral.amazon.dev/help/hub/reference/G200828040
https://www.sellercentral.amazon.dev/help/hub/reference/G201711740

Best regards,

Selling Partner API Developer Support"